# Errors compiling Android LiveTV branch on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu-14.04

I'd like to write a DVB set top box Android UI to access the TV Input Framework in Lollipop. My test hardware comes from iWedia and their github page gives brief instructions on how to download and compile the android-live-tv branch:

> Google is providing a simple TIF compliant TV application with basic TV functionality (LiveTv). This example is tested and approved to work against LiveTv application.
>
> To get and build LiveTv application, run the following command: 
> repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-live-tv 
> repo sync -c -j4 
> . build/envsetup.sh 
> tapas LiveTv 
> make

My compile system is Ubuntu 14.04 with working Android Studio. When I run the make it fails with these [errors](http://pastie.org/10680064) "transitionPosition cannot be resolved or is not a field".

Any help appreciated...

Comment: It looks as though the livetv code branch is currently (as of 19 Jan 2016) broken, as per https://plus.google.com/+NitishSakhawalkar/posts/PAJArGLT7yz